# Проблема Admob и GDPR

Tags: android, admob

Как я понимаю по дефолту Адмоб показывает персонализированную рекламу. Достаточно ли просто добавить следующий код чтобы изменить ее на не персонализированную и не париться с ConsentInformation?

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();  
extras.putString("npa", "1");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()  
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)  
        .build();
```

Или ConsentInformation нужно обязательно добавлять? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Независимо от того, что вы делаете с AdMob, вам всё равно нужно показывать запрос на согласие, т.к. там куча инфы самим sdk отправляется.

Почитайте: [Requesting Consent from European Users](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent).

Там упоминается `AdID`, например. Google в этом плане вообще руководствуется порой старыми доками, про те же Cookies, но от греха подальше лучше показывать запрос.